# Django return new property in json response

Tags: python, json, django

I have a view in Django that fetches some objects, adds new attribute to them and returns them as JSON response.

The code looks like this:

```
def stats(request):
    items = MyItem.objects.all().order_by('-id')

    for item in items:
        item.new_attribute = 10
        
    items_json = serializers.serialize('json', items)

    return HttpResponse(items_json, content_type='application/json')
```

The new_attribute is not visible in JSON response. How can I make it visible in JSON response? It can be accessed in templates normally with {{ item.new_attribute }}.

**EDIT:** I'm using default Django serializer (from django.core import serializers)

Comment: Are you using Django Rest Framework? Do you have a `MyItemSerializer` class? What does it look like? Please [edit] your question to add that code.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Seems like OP referring to [Django Serializer](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/serialization/#serializing-data) not DRF Serializer.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM Thanks for the link. Googling "django serializer" didn't find that immediately. Are serializers in core django new? It's been a while since I worked with Django and I only remember these from DRF. Also...the docs have gotten a facelift since I last looked at them.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice No, It's already available from [Django 1.8](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/serialization/#serializing-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default serializer looks into fields defined in model. Thus, there are two options to resolve it:

1. Add the attribute to your model `MyItem`
2. Use a custom serializer to serialize your model with this dynamic attribute

Example of such serializer:

**serializers.py**

```
class MyItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    new_attribute = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_new_attribute(self, obj):
        if hasattr(obj, 'new_attribute'):
            return obj.new_attribute
        return None

    class Meta:
        model = MyItem
        fields = '__all__'
```

And then in **views.py** it will be:

```
items_json = serializers.MyItemSerializer(items, many=True).data
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are reference `serializers` in your code, I assume that you are using Django REST Framework and have a class named `MyItemSerializer`. This class tells is used by `serializers.serialize()` to determine how to create the JSON string from your model objects. In order to add a new attribute to the JSON string, you need to add the attribute to this class.